# SEO for ecommerce site with 9,000 unique products

Tags: seo, e-commerce

I've just rebuilt my ecommerce site listing about 9,000 different products in 12 different categories divided into many subcategories. Each product is unique. There doesn't seem much hope that Google will ever get round to indexing my full catalogue, so I'm thinking of adding rel=nofollow to all of my category links, leaving only the link that points to the 35 pages of highest value products. Is this a good strategy? What have other people in similar situation done?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think Google can't index 9000 pages? Google has indexed more than 5m pages from SO without a worry: http://www.google.com.sg/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com.

Comment: Ciaran, I don't reckon Google's likely to give the same amount of indexing time to my site as to SO. Or am I misunderstanding how it works?

Comment: If you follow best practices, Google treats all sites equally. Make your site spiderable, and it will be spidered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's never really a good idea to consider `rel="nofollow"` on your own content. The purpose behind that element being used for SEO is to signal that you can't *trust* or *vouch* for that content - is that really the signal you want to send to the Goog?
2. Depth of crawl (crawl budget) is directly proportional to Page Rank, so the more page rank that a site has flowing through it, the more regular and deeper the crawling will occur (this has been confirmed by Google, I'll have to dig for the exact source).
3. If you think Google is going to have problems naturally crawling (and 9,000 product pages is nothing), then you should consider submitting an XML sitemap of your site (via WebMaster Tools) - this will give you a good page-for-page indication on what's been crawled.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Mike. I'm sure Google wouldn't have any problems at all crawling that number of links - my concern is more whether they'll bother in my case. I'll have to learn more about Page Rank. I've submitted XML sitemaps, I'll keep an eye on them.